# 2-Factor Authentication on an MVC App using Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

Is there a good way to implement 2-Factor authentication on an MVC web application that is using Windows Authentication?

I see examples that show how to implement 2-Factor on a Forms-based MVC app, but couldn't find one for a Windows-based MVC app.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2-factor doesn't make sense in the context of Windows Auth. The application is authorized by the user's domain account. The security aspect lies on the domain-end, not the application-end.

However, if you're dead set on doing this, you effectively can't use Windows Auth. That sounds a little contradictory, I know. How you would have to handle this is use application-based authentication, such as Identity, so the web application itself would hold the user accounts. Then, you can authenticate via connecting to LDAP directly. You'll have to set all this up yourself, in other words; no easy set it and forget like you get with Windows Auth. With something like Identity, you can implement 2-factor auth, so you're golden there. However, instead of validating the password via your application's database and users, you authenticate via LDAP.

This is actually pretty common among enterprise-class applications utilizing AD. Typically, they'll have a script that you can run, as a consumer of the app, to periodically update the application's user database from AD, so all the same users with the same details exist in both places, except for the password, which remains solely with AD. This way, the application can associate its own data with its copy of the user, but authentication and authorization still happens at the AD level.